# Use of XAML Style Trigger with TreeView Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView named TaskTree for which each TreeViewItem is a Task object with one property beeng PriorityID.  I set the DataContext of the TreeView as follows:

```
TaskTree.DataContext = AllTasks
```

where AllTasks is an ObserableCollection(Of Task).  I want to changed the background color for each TreeViewItem depending on the value of PriorityID.  I do this in XAML as follows:

```
<Style
    TargetType="TreeView">
    <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Path=PriorityID}" Value="142">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
       </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

While this matches exactly an example on MSDN, the background is not changing and I cannot find the error.

**Edit**
In case it is relevant, here is the setup of the TreeView:

```
<TreeView
    x:Name="TaskTree"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubTasks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style is targeting the tree, but you need to target the item. The way you have it now, it expects PriorityID in the Tree itself, which its not.

Comment: I already had that thought and tried it and got compile error.  But at your prompt I tried it again and setting the trigger in the treeviewitem is correct.  I must have done it wrong in some way.